# Where are the Realm datas stored?

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm new to Realm and I'm using it on React-Native.

I need to know where the datas are stored "physically" in my app, I mean where is the .realm file(s) because I will have to consult these datas at a moment without using any query in the code.

I didn't find this realm file but I think it exists because of Realm Studio which permit to consult datas with a file.

Can someone help me please ? I only need to know that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find the path of the realm file like this:

```
console.log('db path:', db.path)
```

Found the answer in Realm's [docs](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/api/Realm.html)